# Google earth engine: filter a FeatureCollection by system id

Tags: filter, google-earth-engine

I have a `FeatureCollection` in Google Earth Engine, where each Feature is referenced by an `id` tag. How do I filter the `FeatureCollection` based on that id?

Following attempts to filter `id=3` did not work:

```
 // Create a FC (from https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/feature_collections)
var features = [
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Rectangle(30.01, 59.80, 30.59, 60.15), {name: 'Voronoi'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-73.96, 40.781), {name: 'Thiessen'}),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(6.4806, 50.8012), {name: 'Dirichlet'})
];
var FC = ee.FeatureCollection(features);
print(FC, "FC")

// extract basedon ID?
print(FC.filter(ee.Filter.eq("id", 2)))
print(FC.filter(ee.Filter.eq("system:id", 2)))
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is tricky, as there are actually two issues:

- It's called *system:index* even though the UI shows it as *id*.
- The `id` is a string, rather than an integer

So the correct way to do this is:

```js
print(FC.filter(ee.Filter.eq("system:index", '3')))
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to your answer, you could use

`print(g200.filterMetadata('system:index', 'equals', '3'))`

Using either filter looks to do the same thing.